# > Let $E\subsetneq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a vector space. $\mathbb{R}^n-E$ is connected $\iff dim(E) \leq n-2$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, vector-spaces, connectedness

> Let $E\subsetneq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a vector space. $\mathbb{R}^n-E$ is connected $\iff dim(E) \leq n-2$

I was able to prove one way, I couldn't make the other.

$(\Rightarrow)$ Let $\mathbb{R}^n-E$ be connected. Suppose $dim(E)>n-2 \implies dim(E) = n-1$ since $E$ is not $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $B =\{b_1,...,b_{n-1}\}$ orthonormal base of E and $B\cup \{b_n\}$ an orthonormal base for $\mathbb{R}^n$.

$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n-E$, $x = \sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i$, $a_n\not =0$. (if $a_n=0$ then $x \in E$)

Let $A = \{y \in \mathbb{R}^n| y =\sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i$, $a_n>0\} $

Let $C = \{y \in \mathbb{R}^n| y =\sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i$, $a_n<0\} $

$\mathbb{R}^n-E = A \cup C$, $A$ and $C$ are open and $A \cap C = \emptyset$ therefore $\mathbb{R}^n-E$ isn't connected. Contradiction! So $dim(E)\leq n-2$.

Now, what I was attempting for the other part:

($\Leftarrow$)Suppose $dim(E)=m\leq n-2$

Let $B = \{b_1,..,b_m\}$ orthonormal base of $E$ and $B^*=B\cup\{b_{m+1},...,b_n\}$ orthonormal base of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Suppose $\mathbb{R}^n-E = A \cup C$, $A,C$ open sets and $A \cap C = \emptyset$.

I need either to show that A (or C) is an empty set or suppose there's an element in both sets A and C and get to a contradiction. This part I couldn't find a way. Any useful hints?

ps:The first part is correct?

Comment: Your first part is correct (but the orthonormal part is unnecessary). For the second part, you could try proving that $R^n - E$ is path-connected. To get an idea of how this can be done, perhaps look at the cases $n = 2$ and $n = 3$ first. Writing down a basis as you've done is a good step.

Comment: You could simplify your notation greatly, in a way that I think would make the solution obvious, if you answer the following question:

can you think of a matrix, $A\in GL_n(\mathbb{R})$, that will map your subspace $E$ to a specific subspace? Specific meaning...particularly canonical and standard. Since invertible matrices act as homeomorphisms on your space, this means you can assume, w.l.o.g., that $E$ is this specific subspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\text{dim}(E) \leq n - 2$, we can find a linearly independent set $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_k,u_1,u_2\}$, where $\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\}$ is a basis for $E$. Let $W_1 = \text{Span}(v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_k,u_1)$, and $W_2 = \text{Span}(v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_k,u_2)$.

Now for any vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \backslash E$, if $x \notin W_1$, then the straight line connecting $x$ and $u_1$ lies in $\mathbb{R}^{n} \backslash E$, so $x$ and $u_1$ lie in the same connected component of $\mathbb{R}^{n} \backslash E$. Similarly, if $x \notin W_2$, then $x$ and $u_2$ lie in the same connected component of $\mathbb{R}^{n} \backslash E$. And the straight line between $u_1$ and $u_2$ is also in $\mathbb{R}^{n} \backslash E$, so these connected components are the same, and comprise all of $\mathbb{R}^{n} \backslash E$.

Comment: Helpful note: The intersection of $W_1$ with $W_2$ is equal to $E$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $dim(E) \leq n-2$

Here is the solution for Dim($E$) = 1 and n = 3.

Use the standard $x,y,x$ coordinate system with $E$ the $z$-axis.

The set $\{v = (x, y, z) \text{ such that } x^2 + y^2 \gt 0\}$ is the complement of $E$ and is connected since you can path connect any point outside of $E$ to $(1,0,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that the $\mathrm{Dim}(E) \leq n-2$. Then, write down a basis $e_1,e_2, \dots,e_{n-2}$ for $E$, and extend to a full basis by $e_{n-1}, e_n$. Then, given any points  $x,y \in \mathbb R^n-E$, we have that $x=a_{n-1} e_{n-1}+a_ne_n$ and $y=b_{n-1} e_{n-1}+b_n e_n$. In this case, we can construct the line $y-x \in \mathbb R^n-E$, which supplies a perfectly good path between the points, assuming that it does not pass through the origin. From this, it follows that the subspace is path connected, and hence connected.

Explicitly: $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb R^n-E$ given by $f(t):=x+ty=(a_{n-1}+tb_{n-1})e_{n-1}+(a_n+tb_n)e_n$ gives a path.

If the line paases through the  origin, we need only take $c:=(1,\dots,0)$ and construct a path piece-wise through $c$.

Comment: For my 3 dim setup, if you connect (1,0,0) with (-1,0,0) with a line you pass thru the 0 vector.

Comment: woops, that is  completely correct.